# красивый url в yii без index.php

Tags: yii, маршрутизация

чисто стартовый проект, все изменения ниже:
Маршрутизация

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => false,
],
```

Добавил в httpd.conf, пробовал в несколько разных httpd.con

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/basic"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/basic">
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>
```

Ещё не работал defaultRoute, yii говорил, что не знает такого свойства, это было без красивого url

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать файл .htaccess в папке web и добавьте код :

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```